# Any examples on how to use the Camel's BacklogDebugger?

Tags: apache-camel

Well, I decided to hack my own IDEA debugger plugin for Apache Camel. I found some info about the `BacklogDebugger` feature, but I guess I don't really understand how to use it. What puzzles me is how do I get any notification of the breakpoint reached in the running Camel application. Is there any way to add event listeners to the `BacklogDebugger`? Or is there any other feature for that?
I couldn't find any examples of how the BacklogDebugger is used.

Answer (score 0):

The [Hawtio](https://hawt.io) Camel plugin uses `BacklogDebugger` for its Camel route debugging page.

It polls the `getDebugCounter` method to see if there are any new debugged messages and from there it figures out if any breakpoints were hit and retrieves the message exchange content.

You can try to decipher the TypeScript code for inspiration:

https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio-integration/blob/master/plugins/camel/ts/debug/debug.controller.ts

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse Desktop Fuse Tooling is also using it. As it is written in Java, it migth be easier to translate for IntelliJ IDEA plugin.

See https://github.com/jbosstools/jbosstools-fuse/tree/jbosstools-4.21.0.Final/editor/plugins/org.fusesource.ide.launcher/src/org/fusesource/ide/launcher/debug

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to reverse engineer this code but it's a bit too complicated. I still don't understand how do I know if the breakpoint is reached in the VM. Aside from constantly polling `getDebugCounter` in a separate thread and fire notifications, I don't see any better way...

Comment: yeah need to constantly poll.

If someone else is reaching this issue, discussion continued on https://camel.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/258729-camel-tooling/topic/Intellij.20plugin/near/264159704